# Compare vectors by using tolerance with for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have two vectors as an output and they have different lengths. Now, I want to compare each element of one vector with each element of the other vector.

Suppose these are my two vectors:

```
r1 <- c(1.5,3.5,4.5,5.5,8.5,11.5,12.5,17.5)
min <- c(3,6,11)
```

And my compare command looks like this:

```
m1 <- which(abs(outer(min, r1, `-`)) <= 0.5, arr.ind = TRUE)
cbind.data.frame(min = min[m1[,1]], r1 = r1[m1[,2]])
```

It works and gives me this output:

```
  min   r1
1   3  3.5
2   6  5.5
3  11 11.5
```

What I am asking for now is, how to do the same just by using a for loop (probably with if else statement)? I already came up with this solution, but I don't know how to integrate the tolerance (+/- 0.5)...

```
z<-rep(0,length(r1))
for(i in 1:length(r1))
{
  for(j in 1:length(min))
  {
    if(x[j]>y[i])
      z[i]=z[i]+1
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

How to get the min vector as the resulting vector, if I have for example these vectors:

```
 min
[1]  2 15
 r1
[1]  1.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  8.5 11.5 12.5 17.5
```

After running code from @shirin, I get this as result vector:

```
    V1   V2
1    2   1.5
```

With this **error message**:

> Error in rbind(res, cbind(min[i], hc[abs(hc - min[i]) <= 0.5])) :
>   number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)

Now I want to have my **min vector as the resulting vector if my res vector only gives me one row**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
res<-NULL
for (i in 1:length(min)){
   res<-rbind(res,cbind(min[i],r1[abs(r1-min[i])<=0.5]))
}
res
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    3  3.5
#[2,]    6  5.5
#[3,]   11 11.5
```